# How to retrieve the time column value from oracleDB into .net application

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle table where there is one date-time field.
On select query i am able to get all the field values but not timefield value in my .net application.

```
select abc.Id, abc.Name, abc.When from details abc where abc.Id='"+1234+"'
```

Could anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the returned `DATE` field from Oracle depends upon your default [NLS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm) settings in the database.

Oracle stores dates (and times) in an internal representation and when you select the date values you can then format them as you need. An official Oracle explaination is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847).

To force the format you can explicitly convert the date to a string representation using:

```
select abc.Id, 
       abc.Name, 
       TO_CHAR(abc.When, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS when 
  from details abc 
 where abc.Id='"+1234+"'
```

If you are ONLY wanting the time portion of the `WHEN` column then:

```
select abc.Id, 
       abc.Name, 
       TO_CHAR(abc.When, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS when 
  from details abc 
 where abc.Id='"+1234+"'
```

This will then return it as a string rather than a date and time which may or may not be OK for you depending upon what you then want to do with it.
The format you choose for the date and time could be any of the Oracle date and time formats, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm).

Hope it helps...